# Notation for image and kernel capitalization of first letter

Tags: notation

In the mathematical notation for image and kernel one usually writes $\ker$ for kernel and $\DeclareMathOperator{\img}{Im}\img$ for image. Why is the "k" small but the "I" big?

Comment: I do not capitalize $\text{im}$.

Comment: I don't capitalize $\text{im}$ either. Some people capitalize $\text{Ker}$, even. It's a wild world out there.

Comment: There is no uniform notation: both are capitalised in French.

Comment: I don't capitalize either , since $Im$ can refer to an imaginary part

Comment: ok great thanks for the comments. I will write both small then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CW answer summing up comments, to push it from unanswered queue:

There is no uniform notation. It may or may not be capitalised.